# Django -- User' object has no attribute 'backend' When Registering New User

Tags: python, django

Working on a sign up form, and when all inputs are submitted, the user is correctly populated in database, but the web page is generating the following error:

`AttributeError at /accounts/sign_up/
'User' object has no attribute 'backend'`

i've searched for the last hour but can't figure what this issue might be

i don't see any backend declared in settings, but i thought that this was automatically set with built in Django Auth?

Anyways here is my stack trace:

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\crstu\Desktop\JSPROJ\dealmazing\accounts\views.py" in sign_up
  55.             login(request, user)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in login
  112.     request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY] = user.backend

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in inner
  205.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /accounts/sign_up/
Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute 'backend'
```

which appears to be pointing back to my `sign_up` view here:

```
def sign_up(request):
    form = forms.UserCreateForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.UserCreateForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            user = authenticate(
                username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
                email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            )
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(
                request,
                "You're now a user! You've been signed in, too."
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))  # TODO: go to profile
    return render(request, 'accounts/sign_up.html', {'form': form})
```

and here is my custom UserCreateForm:

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    """Form for creating a new user."""
    verify_email = forms.EmailField(label="Please verify your email address.")

    class Meta:
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'verify_email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        ]
        model = get_user_model()

    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        email = data.get('email')
        verify = data.get('verify_email')

        if email != verify:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "You need to enter the same email in both fields"
            )
        return data
```

and my custom User model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='')
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def get_long_name(self):
        return "@{} ({})".format(self.username, self.email)
```

Comment: What is `authenticate` here? Is it the one from django.contrib.auth?

Comment: yes. exactly, should have made that more clear

Comment: so i think i know what the issue is...since i have `username_field` set as 'email' in User model, i should only be authenticating using the email and password, instead of username, email and password--thanks for steering me in right direction